# Lubuntu update network-manager

Tags: lubuntu, network-manager

I just installed lubuntu on a pcDuino3 and it is ok. I would just like to upgrade network-manager to 0.9.8.10 or anything greater than 0.9.6. It tried and built version 0.9.7.977 but on reboot network-manager wouldn't start. Anybody know how I can update it on Lubuntu 12.04. I need to upgrade to get the newer version of `nmcli`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you are aware of it but Lubuntu 12.04 has reached its End of Life which means that you will no longer receive updates, patches, or security fixes.  The newest and only currently supported version of Lubuntu (14.04) has 0.9.8.8 installed.  Since Lubuntu 12.04 was not a LTS version I am not even sure that you can upgrade to Lubuntu 14.04.  Recommend that you do a fresh install after you back up all of your data.

Comment: Yep. I just changed my sources.list and lsb-release to 14.04, and installed the latest version.